# 404 error while trying to view html file in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am new to tomcat. I have just begun reading headfirst's servlets book. I have installed tomcat and I am able to view the content under //http://localhost:8080/examples/. The book mentions to create a folder called "beer" under the webapps folder in tomcat. Then in this folder place the .html file and WEB-INF folder which houses the web.xml file. However, when I try to run //http://localhost:8080/beer I get a 404 error. I have read another post from stackoverflow that advises to add a jsp file but the book does not mention this to display the .html file. Any advice much appreciated?

Eventually solved this error..It was a simple parsing error caused by copying code from online. The apostrophes were incorrect in the web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your web.xml file you have the declaration of your html file in welcome file list tag .like

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

and your html file name should be there .

Comment: Hey neeraj thanks for the reply. The html file is saved as index.html so I am assuming there is no need for me to add this content to the web.xml file??

Comment: Do I need a .jsp file to just display / render the html page?